# Ejecting USB dslr camera

Tags: usb, camera, peripherals

I'm using gphoto2 to capture images with my nikon dslr connected to a raspberry Zero W

My problem is that the camera stayes awake as long as there is a usb connection.

How can I eject the USB connection?

dmesg:

```
[  229.503626] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[  229.713448] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[  229.713817] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[  229.954634] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04b0, idProduct=0422, bcdDevice= 1.03
[  229.954680] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  229.954694] usb 1-1: Product: NIKON DSC D700
[  229.954703] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: NIKON
[  229.954713] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000002138587
[  280.823566] fuse init (API version 7.27)
[  293.303738] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 7518.546891] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[ 7518.756694] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[ 7518.757056] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[ 7518.997887] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04b0, idProduct=0422, bcdDevice= 1.03
[ 7518.997934] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7518.997947] usb 1-1: Product: NIKON DSC D700
[ 7518.997956] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: NIKON
[ 7518.997965] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000002138587
[ 7544.347332] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 8400.807853] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[ 8401.017718] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[ 8401.018079] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[ 8401.258897] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04b0, idProduct=0422, bcdDevice= 1.03
[ 8401.258945] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8401.258957] usb 1-1: Product: NIKON DSC D700
[ 8401.258966] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: NIKON
[ 8401.258977] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000002138587
[ 8402.857993] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 9503.571529] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[ 9503.781365] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[ 9503.781717] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[ 9504.022547] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04b0, idProduct=0422, bcdDevice= 1.03
[ 9504.022596] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 9504.022607] usb 1-1: Product: NIKON DSC D700
[ 9504.022617] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: NIKON
[ 9504.022626] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000002138587
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your camera detects a USB connection - whether it's by detecting that's power is provided through the USB cable, or whether by detecting that there's an actual USB connection happening in software. In the latter case, there's a software solution that works out-of-the-box, and that's the one you should check first. Provided the camera is the only device connected to the Zero W, you can disable the USB port data connection (not power!) in software:

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/buspower
```

After this, `lsusb` will no longer show your camera as a device. If the camera detects this as a disconnection and goes to sleep, then you're in luck! Changing `echo 0` to `echo 1` and re-running this command will enable the the USB connection again, state of the USB connection will not persist across a reboot AFAIK.

---

If this does not work out for you, your camera might be using the USB power connection in order to detect whether it's "connected to a PC". In this case, you can use a power switch of some sorts, one that will cut the power connection. I sell this kind of USB switches (for this and many other purposes) [on Tindie](https://www.tindie.com/products/CRImier/usb-power-drug/), here's the schematic I use:

[image: mosfet-driven USB power switch schematic]

The data lines and GND pass through unchanged. `CTRL` is connected to a Raspberry Pi GPIO, `+5V` is the power line from the Pi Zero, and `+5VD` is going to the camera. R2 and R3 are used to set the default state of the switch (default *off* unless set *on* - vs default *on* unless set *off*), you only need one of these at a time. I use IRLML6401 (alternative: CJ2305) for Q2, and 2N2222 (alternative: BC547) for Q1. You can also use a relay to replace the FET - it will be a simpler circuit, but will consume more power.

Comment: Thanks, you were right..my rpi obviously can't power off usb

Comment: @user3435167 but did the "software switch off" work out in the end? It works with a couple of phones I had to have connected, but didn't work with i.e. a USB microscope I was using (which would switch to the "USB camera mode" even if I just wanted to power it from a laptop).

Answer (score 1):

You can download the [eject package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/eject) with `sudo apt-get install eject`. Here's the [eject syntax](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/eject.htm).

Remember, in order to eject a device, you first need to unmount it.

Comment: How do I figure out the correct path? The camera is not mounted as a mass storage in order to work with gphoto2 I updated my answer

Comment: @user3435167, is it not listed under `/dev/`?

Comment: No unfortunately  
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gphoto2 --auto-detect 
Modell                         Port                                            
----------------------------------------------------------
Nikon DSC D700 (PTP mode)      usb:001,009   `

Comment: Have you checked the `/media/user/` directory?

Comment: mh what do I have to type to check it? cd /media/user/  didnt work

Comment: If your `/media` directory is empty then it's not there either. Have you checked if gphoto allows you to unmount a device?

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried using `lsusb` to see your USB devices?

Comment: lsusb gives:
`Bus 001 Device 014: ID 04b0:0422 Nikon Corp. D700 (ptp)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`             
         i havent found anything that worked with gphoto directly

Comment: OK, can you check in your `/dev` directory if you have a device called `ttyUSB0`? If so, one quick way to check if your camera is that device is to run the following in your `home` or `desktop` (doesn't really matter) directory: `ls /dev dev1.txt` then unplug your camera and type `ls /dev dev2.txt` and finally type `diff dev1.txt dev2.txt`. If you get an output it should be your device and it would mean that it is indeed listed under the `/dev` directory.

Comment: No, there is no ttyUSB0

Comment: Did you try using `diff` before and after unplugging the camera?